# ユーザーアクティビティの票タブで票の種類が読み辛い

Tags: バグ, 完了

タイトル通りです。
機能的には何も問題はないのですが、英語版に比べると酷いので一応報告を。

---

In the "Votes Cast" tab in User Activity page, the type of vote (in red / green text) is very hard to read, compared to the English version. The text goes sideways, but the line only fits 2 characters. Function wise there's no problem; just looks really bad...

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1767/8000 でも言及されてますが、ほかのタブも同じことがおきますね。日本語版では `white-space: nowrap` か `word-break: keep-all` を付けてもらえるといいのですが・・・。

Comment: 探したのですが、やっぱり報告はされてたんですね。自分の環境だと`white-space: nowrap`だとほぼ大丈夫（マイナス投票は1文字改行される、ただずっと良い見た目）ですが、`word-break: keep-all`は効きませんでした

Comment: 「マイナス投票が改行」の部分ですが全ての`td`に`white-space: nowrap`適応してないだけでした…

Answer (score 3):

現在は問題が無くなっています。デザイン変更に伴ない直ったものと思われます。

> [image: スクリーンショット]